# Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, jpa, flyway

I m trying to run my project Spring boot with mysql and flyway

My environement:

- Linux 18.04
- Java 1.8.0_201
- Spring boot and this my pom.xml

4.0.0

org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-parent
2.3.1.RELEASE
 

com.mhanzouli
tutorial
0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
tutorial
Test Swagger/Actuator/Log4j2/Flyway

```
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <!--<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
        <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

application.yml

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/tutorial_bd?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false
    username: root
    password:
  jpa:
    show-sql: true
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: validate
      naming-strategy: org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
  flyway:
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/tutorial_bd
    user: "root"
    password:
    baselineOnMigrate: true
    check-location: true
    locations: classpath:db/migration
    enabled: true
```

V1__init.sql

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  id bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  username varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  first_name varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  last_name varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  UNIQUE KEY UK_username (username)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

User.java

```
package com.mhanzouli.tutorial.domain;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotBlank
    @Column(unique = true)
    @Size(min = 1, max = 100)
    private String username;

    @NotBlank
    @Size(max = 50)
    private String firstName;

    @Size(max = 50)
    private String lastName;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
}
```

[this is my project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CWdj0.png)

And when i execute

```
mvn spring-boot:run
```

i got this error

```
2020-06-20 21:19:54.540  INFO 13594 --- [           main] c.m.tutorial.TutorialApplication         : Starting TutorialApplication on marwen with PID 13594 (/home/marwen/Bureau/projects/tutorial/target/classes started by marwen in /home/marwen/Bureau/projects/tutorial)
2020-06-20 21:19:54.543  INFO 13594 --- [           main] c.m.tutorial.TutorialApplication         : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-06-20 21:19:55.337  INFO 13594 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFERRED mode.
2020-06-20 21:19:55.364  INFO 13594 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 19ms. Found 0 JPA repository interfaces.
2020-06-20 21:19:55.962  INFO 13594 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2020-06-20 21:19:55.971  INFO 13594 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2020-06-20 21:19:55.971  INFO 13594 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.36]
2020-06-20 21:19:56.045  INFO 13594 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2020-06-20 21:19:56.046  INFO 13594 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1452 ms
2020-06-20 21:19:56.196  INFO 13594 --- [           main] o.f.c.internal.license.VersionPrinter    : Flyway Community Edition 6.4.4 by Redgate
2020-06-20 21:19:56.310  INFO 13594 --- [           main] o.f.c.internal.database.DatabaseFactory  : Database: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/tutorial_bd (MySQL 5.5)
2020-06-20 21:19:56.366  WARN 13594 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flywayInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.flywaydb.core.internal.license.FlywayEditionUpgradeRequiredException: Flyway Pro Edition or MariaDB upgrade required: MariaDB 10.1 is no longer supported by Flyway Community Edition, but still supported by Flyway Pro Edition.
2020-06-20 21:19:56.369  INFO 13594 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2020-06-20 21:19:56.382  INFO 13594 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2020-06-20 21:19:56.392 ERROR 13594 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flywayInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.flywaydb.core.internal.license.FlywayEditionUpgradeRequiredException: Flyway Pro Edition or MariaDB upgrade required: MariaDB 10.1 is no longer supported by Flyway Community Edition, but still supported by Flyway Pro Edition.
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1796) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:595) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1109) ~[spring-context-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869) ~[spring-context-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:551) ~[spring-context-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:143) ~[spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758) [spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750) [spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237) [spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) [spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
        at com.mhanzouli.tutorial.TutorialApplication.main(TutorialApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.flywaydb.core.internal.license.FlywayEditionUpgradeRequiredException: Flyway Pro Edition or MariaDB upgrade required: MariaDB 10.1 is no longer supported by Flyway Community Edition, but still supported by Flyway Pro Edition.
        at org.flywaydb.core.internal.database.base.Database.ensureDatabaseNotOlderThanOtherwiseRecommendUpgradeToFlywayEdition(Database.java:173) ~[flyway-core-6.4.4.jar:na]
        at org.flywaydb.core.internal.database.mysql.MySQLDatabase.ensureSupported(MySQLDatabase.java:287) ~[flyway-core-6.4.4.jar:na]
        at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.execute(Flyway.java:514) ~[flyway-core-6.4.4.jar:na]
        at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.migrate(Flyway.java:159) ~[flyway-core-6.4.4.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayMigrationInitializer.afterPropertiesSet(FlywayMigrationInitializer.java:65) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1855) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1792) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
        ... 19 common frames omitted

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  10.089 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-06-20T21:19:56+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.3.1.RELEASE:run (default-cli) on project tutorial: Application finished with exit code: 1 -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Comment: What about the line that reads `Caused by: org.flywaydb.core.internal.license.FlywayEditionUpgradeRequiredException: Flyway Pro Edition or MariaDB upgrade required: MariaDB 10.1 is no longer supported by Flyway Community Edition, but still supported by Flyway Pro Edition.`

Answer (score 0):

The exception says "MariaDB 10.1 is no longer supported". Use newer version of Maria DB, e.g. the current version 10.5.3, and corresponding version of JDBC driver for it.

Comment: I not used maria db , i only use mysql 5.7 , you mean the version of Flyway or mysql jdbc?

Comment: According to stacktrace you want Flyway to use outdated version of Maria DB JDBC Driver. Check where it comes from, e.g. it might by a transitive dependency of spring-boot-starter-data-jpa.

Answer (score 0):

This restriction is no longer in place from Flyway version 10 (October 2023). We have updated Flyway so that it works with ALL supported database versions, so if you upgrade to version 10 you can access all supported versions of MariaDB.

The community version of Flyway now works with All versions of MariaDB.